# Qt static linking in Windows: successful in for one app, but unsuccessful for the other

Tags: windows, qt

I have succeeded in creating a statically linked version of an app in Windows. I have (1) compiled Qt statically and (2) compiled my application with the static version of Qt using the Qt Creator (see the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html), and more in detail the [steps I followed](http://dimitris.apeiro.gr/2015/06/24/build-a-static-qt5-for-windows-by-compiling/)). This works great, and I'm able to distribute the app.

Now I'm trying to compile a different app, with **the same compiler and settings** in Qt Creator, but somehow the `.exe` ends up dynamically linked....?? Note that I have statically compiled both applications successfully on macOS.

What is going wrong?

> I realize that this remains a wide question, but any suggestions are very much welcome.
>
> I have tried so far to add `CONFIG+=static` to the `.pro` file (although that was not needed for the first app). Also here this had no effect.

Comment: Make sure /MT compiler option is used in your project and that should match statically built Qt. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx

Comment: @AlexanderVX Wow, even with my broad question you might have pinpointed it to the correct point. I'm quite unfamiliar with Windows, do I give this as an option to `configure` when compiling the static version of Qt? Also how does it relate to using MinGW?

Comment: @"Tom de Geus" See, if you did not mess with own Qt build compiler options and the compiler is MS Visual C++ then it should have been compiled with -MT(d) for the static build. Then the application project that don't compile appears to be a culprit. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485810/cannot-compile-a-simple-qt-program-in-mt-mode-as-opposed-to-md-in-visual-studio and here https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MSVC

Comment: Also, if you link with libraries besides Qt you could have introduced the problem so we need the project file and the error log.